# Ansible: Ignore errors and move to the next node

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

My ansible playbook is setup to install docker on all the nodes in a cluster
As my input, i parse a list(array) of node ips and create my inventory file.
In a loop, i run this playbook for each node.
What i observe is that the playbook fails and doesn't proceed to complete the installation on the following nodes if even one of the previous nodes fails(unreachable host)

How can i ignore this error and run the playbook for all the nodes in my list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `ignore_unreachable: yes` to your play. There are 2 important things to take note of though:

1. This needs Ansible version >= 2.7
2. If the task fails for any reason **other** than "host unreachable" then it will still abort the play. If you want to continue in this scenario, you will also need to add `ignore_errors: yes`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this.  The runbook continues to the following nodes on both unreachable errors and task errors.

```
---
- hosts: all
  ignore_unreachable: true
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.ping:
      register: ping

    - when: ping.ping is defined
      block:
        - import_tasks: you_main_tasks.yml
      rescue:
        - ansible.builtin.debug:
            msg: failed
```